# How can I rearrange paragraphs of information into a form which can be easily taken to csv?

Tags: powershell

I'm new to PS and I am currently trying to make a PS script which can rearrange paragraphs with specific information into a form which can be easily taken to csv file.

#### The initial information looks like that:

IP Address: 192.168.1.1

Host Name: Test

Domain: contoso.com

IP Address: 192.168.1.2

Host Name: Test2

Domain: contoso.com

#### And i want to rearrange this info to look like that:

IP Address; Host Name; Domain;

192.168.1.1; Test; contoso.com

192.168.1.2; Test2; contoso.com

Would it be possible to do it and could you give me some examples? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi.  Can you post the code you used already?  It goes a long way to showing these folks way smarter than me how you got what you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution :

**Sample input file :**

```
IP Address: 192.168.1.1

Host Name: Test

Domain: contoso.com

IP Address: 192.168.1.2

Host Name: Test2

Domain: contoso.com
```

**Script**

```
Clear-Host

#loads the input file and removes the blank lines
$raw = Get-Content "G:\input\rawinfo.txt" | Where-Object { $_ -ne "" }

#declare results array
$results = @()

#foreach line in the input file
$raw | % {

    #split the line on ": "
    $data = $_ -Split ": "

    #switch on first cell of data
    switch ($data[0]) {

        #store ip address
        "IP Address" { $ipaddress= $data[1] } 

        #store host name
        "Host Name" { $hostname = $data[1] }

        #store domain
        "Domain" {
            $domain = $data[1]

            #since this is the last field for each item

            #build object with all fields
            $item = [PSCustomObject]@{
                "IP Address" = $ipaddress;
                "Host Name" = $hostname;
                "Domain" = $domain;            
            }

            #add object to results array
            $results += $item
        }
    }
}

#output results array
$results
```

**Example output :**

```
IP Address  Host Name Domain     
----------  --------- ------     
192.168.1.1 Test      contoso.com
192.168.1.2 Test2     contoso.com
```

You can then pipe it to `Export-Csv` :

```
$results | Export-Csv "host_info.csv" -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that the information is on a text file
First you need to import the file using **Import-CSV** , process the data and export it as NewCSV.csv

Here is a code example :

```
Import-Csv C:\test.txt -Delimiter ":" -Header "Name", "Value" |export-csv c:\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This should create a file that looks like this :

```
"Name","Value"
"IP Address","192.168.1.1"
"Host Name","Test"
"Domain","contoso.com"
"IP Address","192.168.1.2"
"Host Name","Test2"
"Domain","contoso.com"
```

you can change the delimiter using `-Delimiter ";"`

```
Import-Csv C:\test.txt -Delimiter ":" -Header "Name", "Value" |export-csv c:\test.csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";"
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Maybe i was misunderstood. Actually i'm trying to sort out all IP addresses under one column, in a second column all host names and in a third column all domain names.

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood your question. i'll update as soon as i find a solution.